# How to solve algebraically the equation $x = \frac{1}{2}\cos\left(\frac 2 3 \sin\left(\frac 3 4 x\right)\right) + 1$

Tags: trigonometry, functional-equations

How to solve this trigonometric equation $x = \frac 1 2 \cos\left(\frac 2 3 \sin\left(\frac 3 4 x\right)\right) + 1$ ?

The iterative solution seems to be 1.417.

Can anybody suggest an algebraic solution ?
Does it really exist ?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to solve that nasty looking thing? I'm pretty sure even $x = \cos x$ doesn't have a closed-form solution, so I wouldn't hold out much hope for a nice solution to your equation...

Comment: @Rahul. It is related to a contraction mapping problem.

Comment: I don't know if this helps you, but after I made the above comment I went looking for a proof that the solution to $x = \cos x$ cannot in fact be expressed in closed form. It turns out that, according to [Timothy Chow's 1999 article](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2589148), this is actually still open! It would be implied by [Schanuel's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture), but that conjecture is not proven. Perhaps you can adapt Chow's argument to reduce your problem to Schanuel's conjecture too.

Comment: Shanuel would show it is transcendental, I guess, but that does *not* mean it cannot be expressed in closed form.

Comment: In fact, Schanuel implies much more, the algebraic independence of $\pi$ and $e$, which Timothy Chow was able to extend to show that no solution to $x = \cos x$ can be expressed in closed form (as precisely defined in Chow's paper). See Theorem 1 on p. 443 of Chow's paper. A URL for a freely available version is <http://www-math.mit.edu/~tchow/closedform.pdf>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get extremely accurate approximations using (for example) [Wims function calculator](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/wims.cgi?session=II2021B30D.2&%20lang=en&%20cmd=resume&%20module=tool/analysis/function.en), by searching the root $x^*$ of
$$
f(x) = x - \bigg[\frac{1}{2}\cos \bigg(\frac{2}{3}\sin \bigg(\frac{3}{4}x\bigg)\bigg) + 1\bigg]
$$
(say between $-5$ and $5$). 
Computing its value up to a mild number of digits gives
$$
x^* = 1.417520004.... 
$$
While [Inverse symbolic calculator](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=%201.417520004&lookup_type=simple) does not recognize this, it does lead to the approximation
$$
x^* \approx \frac{{10 \sin (1)}}{{e^{\exp (\gamma )} }} = 1.417520089... ,                                                $$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant ($=0.5772156649...$).